# A system of polynomial equations with odd degree

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

Consider real numbers $u_1, u_3,u_5 \in \mathbb{R}$ and the polynomial system

$
x + y +z= u_1 \\
x^3 + y^3 +z^3= u_3 \\
x^5 + y^5 +z^5= u_5 \\
$

How to prove that the polynomial system has only one solution up to permutations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) and solve for $e_1=x+y+z\,$, $e_2=xy+yz+zx\,$, $e_3=xyz\,$.

Comment: Dear @dxiv many thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative, and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, $x^3+y^3+z^3=27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3$ and

$x^5+y^5+z^5=243u^5-405u^3v^2+135uv^4+45u^2w^3-15v^2w^3$

Thus, we get an easy system on $v^2$ and $w^3$ and the rest is proving of a cubic equation.

Comment: many thanks for the answer.